# Numpy calculation too slow compared to Fortran

Tags: python, numpy

I used to mainly use the Fortran, but recently I started using python and Numpy for deep-learning application.

But, calculating the double for-loop in python was significantly slower than the Fortran. I already knew the Fortran is originally fast in calculation, but I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my python code. This is the code I used as follows:

```
for it in range(nt):
    if it%20 == 1:
        print(it,'//',nt)

    itimenum4 = "%.4i" %(it)
    
    ppsix2[:,:]=0.; ppsiz2[:,:]=0.
    apsix2[:,:]=0.; apsiz2[:,:]=0.
    ax[:,:]=0.; az[:,:]=0.
    p3[:,:]=0.
    
    for iz in range(2,nnz+1):
        for ix in range(2,nnx+1):

            pdx2=(p2[ix+1,iz]-p2[ix,iz])*a1+(p2[ix+2,iz]-p2[ix-1,iz])*a2
            pdz2=(p2[ix,iz+1]-p2[ix,iz])*a1+(p2[ix,iz+2]-p2[ix,iz-1])*a2

            dpml0=math.log(1./R)*3.*vp[ix,iz]/(2.*dx*pml)

            if ix <= pml:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(pml-ix+1)/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                ppsix2[ix,iz]=damp*ppsix1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*pdx2

            if ix >nx+pml:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(ix-(nx+pml))/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                ppsix2[ix,iz]=damp*ppsix1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*pdx2

            if iz > nz:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(iz-(nz))/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                ppsiz2[ix,iz]=damp*ppsiz1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*pdz2

            ax[ix,iz]=pdx2+ppsix2[ix,iz]
            az[ix,iz]=pdz2+ppsiz2[ix,iz]
        
    az[:,1]=az[:,2]
    az[:,0]=az[:,3]

    for iz in range(2,nnz+1):
        for ix in range(2,nnx+1):
            adx=a1*(ax[ix,iz]-ax[ix-1,iz])+a2*(ax[ix+1,iz]-ax[ix-2,iz])
            adz=a1*(az[ix,iz]-az[ix,iz-1])+a2*(az[ix,iz+1]-az[ix,iz-2])

            dpml0=math.log(1./R)*3.*vp[ix,iz]/(2.*dx*pml)

            if ix <= pml:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(pml-ix+1)/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                apsix2[ix,iz]=damp*apsix1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*adx

            if ix > nx+pml:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(ix-(nx+pml))/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                apsix2[ix,iz]=damp*apsix1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*adx

            if iz > nz:
                dpml=dpml0*(float(iz-(nz))/float(pml))**2
                damp=math.exp(-dpml*dt)
                apsiz2[ix,iz]=damp*apsiz1[ix,iz]+(damp-1.)*adz

            px2=adx+apsix2[ix,iz]
            pz2=adz+apsiz2[ix,iz]

            p3[ix,iz]=2.*p2[ix,iz]-p1[ix,iz]+(dt*vp[ix,iz])**2*((px2+pz2)+srcf[ix,iz]*source[it])

            if iz == recz:
                mod_p[ix,it]=p3[ix,iz]

    p3[:,0:2]=0.

    p1[:,:]=p2[:,:]
    p2[:,:]=p3[:,:]
    ppsix1[:,:]=ppsix2[:,:]
    ppsiz1[:,:]=ppsiz2[:,:]
    apsix1[:,:]=apsix2[:,:]
    apsiz1[:,:]=apsiz2[:,:]
```

This is the conventional first-order acoustic wave equation in geophysics. Anyway, I used the Numpy array. Is there any factors that makes calculation slow?

Thanks.

Comment: After I applied vectorization to my code, the calculation time is significantly reduced. Thanks for careful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately since python is an interpreted language (compared to Fortran which is compiled) you will not be able to get similar speed when using python for loops.

There are a few ways to get around this. One way is try to vectorize your for loops using numpy arrays and numpy math functions. By doing this you will pass off the computationally heavy parts of the code to the numpy library which is precompiled.

Another way to speed up your python code is to use a library to compile your code. One such library is numba which provides just-in-time compilation options.

Answer (score 1):

Almost none of the work looks like it's vectorized -- e.g., it's doing things like extracting the single element `ppsize1[ix,iz]` for use in a multiplication.

Numpy doesn't compile down into something fast like Fortran will -- it's fast by having fast routines for operating on large chunks of data at once. If you don't explicitly encode the vectorizeable portions of your algorithm then numpy will be slower than even vanilla python.